# Summing data frames with different length

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data sets (one for each country) that look like this:

```
dfGermany
Country Sales Year Code
Germany 2000  2000 221
Germany 1500  2001 150
Germany 2150  2002 270

dfJapan
Country Sales Year Code    
Japan   500   2000 221
Japan   750   2001 221
Japan   800   2001 270
Japan   1000  2002 270
```

`Code` here is the "name" of the product. What I want to do is to take half the Japanese sell and add it to the df for Germany **if** the `code` **and** the `year` matches.

So for instance, half of the sales value for product `221` and `270` in `dfJapan` (250 € and 500 €) should be added to `dfGermany` for year `2000` and `2002`. But nothing should happen to the values for `2001` since the `code` does not match with the `year`.

I tried with `merge`, but that function did not work since the data is of different size and I also want to match both year and value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do a join on 'Year', 'Code' and then update the 'dfGermany' 'Sales' column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dfGermany)[dfJapan, Sales := Sales + i.Sales/2, on = .(Year, Code)]
dfGermany
#   Country Sales Year Code
#1: Germany  2250 2000  221
#2: Germany  1500 2001  150
#3: Germany  2650 2002  270
```

#### data

```
dfGermany <- structure(list(Country = c("Germany", "Germany", "Germany"), 
Sales = c(2000, 1500, 2150), Year = 2000:2002, Code = c(221L, 
150L, 270L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

dfJapan <- structure(list(Country = c("Japan", "Japan", "Japan", "Japan"
), Sales = c(500L, 750L, 800L, 1000L), Year = c(2000L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2002L), Code = c(221L, 221L, 270L, 270L)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: I get `logical error. i is not a data.table, but 'on' argument is provided.`

Comment: @KGB91 I convert to `data.table` with `setDT`.  I am using `packageVersion('data.table')#
[1] ‘1.11.4’`

Comment: I have `1.11.8`. I tried putting that `setDT` first, but without success.

Comment: @KGB91  Okay, can you try `setDT(dfJapan)` and then use the code above

Comment: That is a strange error because you have converted to data.table.  Can you try it on a fresh session

Comment: The problem seems to lie with one of the two df I want to merge in the real data. Two of them works, but the third one does not work. I'll check when I am back at office tomorrow.

Comment: @KGB91 Can you check the `str` of that dataset?  Is it a `tbl_df` with some attributes.  Then, convert it to `data.frame` first .  It may have some attributes that is preventing it to work correctly

Comment: That might be the issue (will check tomorrow). I should mention that the df that is the problem uses scientific numbers, is that a problem?

Comment: @KGB91  It wouldn't be a problem.  But, check if there are some strange attributes

Comment: `Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 83 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Code         : chr  "150" "150" "150" "150" ...
 $ Year         : num  2014 2015 2016 2017 2007 ...
 $ Country: chr  "Sweden" "Sweden" "Sweden" "Sweden" ...
 $ Value : num  123 124 124 144 222...
 - attr(*, "vars")= chr  "Code" "Year"
 - attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "indices")=List of 83`

(note that code should be chr, since the real code has some letters in it)

Edit: I used `as.data.frame` and now it seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` and @akrun's provided data:

```
library(dplyr)

dfGermany %>%
  left_join(dfJapan %>%
              select(Year, Code, sales_japan = Sales),
            by = c('Year', 'Code')) %>%
  mutate(Sales = Sales + coalesce(sales_japan / 2, 0)) %>%
  select(-sales_japan)

> dfGermany
  Country Sales Year Code
1 Germany  2250 2000  221
2 Germany  1500 2001  150
3 Germany  2650 2002  270
```